# Which software/platform to develop a web application based on map

Tags: web-apps, maps

I'm looking for an optimal solution in order to create a web app which shows information on a map.

Information can be:

- Placemarks, which on clic show relevant information on a tooltip
- Shapes/areas, based on GeoJSONs or similar formats with custom coloring/format and the possibility to be clicked as well

Generally speaking, I'm planning to store the data on a relational database (e.g. Postgres) or a non-relational one (e.g. MongoDB).

The more the platform has a smooth learning curve, the better.

Solutions I have considered so far are ArcGIS and Mapbox.
I was interested understanding if there are other recommended options too.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You can try Syncfusion JavaScript Map Control

https://www.syncfusion.com/javascript-ui-controls/js-maps

Syncfusion offers a free community license also. https://www.syncfusion.com/products/communitylicense

Note: I work for Syncfusion